# SwiftUI binding to specific enum case or cases

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, enums, combine

When a SwiftUI view has a complex logic, i like to employ an enum to represent it's state (often in a viewmodel/service).

```
struct FooView {

    enum ProgressState {
        case idle
        case loading
        case completed(Model)
        case error

        var stateName: String { ... }
    }

    @State var state: ProgressState = .idle
    ...
```

**PROBLEM:**

What i'd like tho, is a way or methodology to connect bindables to a specific enum case. In this example, to show an alert (or a sheet), since something like `<<$state.error>>` is obviously not possible.

```
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text(state.stateName)

        // show alert on error
        .alert("oops there was an error", 
               isPresented: <<$state.error>>) 
        { //1.
            ...
        }
        
    }
}
```

**CURRENT ALTERNATIVE**

The easiest solution is to use additional variables, but i really do not like to keep them synchronised manually.

**BETTER SOLUTIONS?**

I was exploring using combine to update the additional variable upon `state` var changes, the problem is always that the bindable needs to change it's state as well, but in this case the alert, does not know to which state to bring it back to.

So maybe a protocol for the enum and an extension to alert and sheet to handle these instead of Bindable ? Has anybody tried a similar approach or know a better one?

Thank you

Comment: What happen if user tap "OK"? State should become idle? reload? undefined? nil? This question itself is the answer to your question.

Comment: Yes this is the main issue, and that's what i meant with the protocol for the enum, i forgot a paragraph, correcting, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI provides a solution to present `LocalizedError`

```
func alert<E, A>(
    isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
    error: E?,
    @ViewBuilder actions: () -> A
) -> some View where E : LocalizedError, A : View
```

You can create a simple `enum` that can present any standard `Error` or custom errors.

```
enum LocalError: LocalizedError {
    //Use for any built in error
    case error(Error)
    //Use for something custom
    case invalidId
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .error(let error):
            return error.localizedDescription
        case .invalidId:
            return "\(self)"
        }
    }
    var recoverySuggestion: String? {
        switch self {
        case .error(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedRecoverySuggestion
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can modify your progress enum.

```
enum ProgressState {
    case idle
    case loading
    case completed(Model)
    case error(Error)
```

You can then trigger an `alert` (or sheet) when that state is triggered

```
switch state {
case .error(let error):
    Text(state.stateName)
        .task {
            alert = (true, .error(error))
        }
default :
    Text(state.stateName)
}
```

Here is the full code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FooView: View {
    
    enum ProgressState {
        case idle
        case loading
        case completed(Model)
        case error(LocalError)
        
        
        var stateName: String {
            switch self {
            case .completed(_):
                return "Complete"
            case .error(_):
                return "Something went wrong"
            default:
                return "\(self)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    @State private var state: ProgressState = .idle
    @State private var alert: (isPresented: Bool, error: LocalError?) = (false, nil)
    var body: some View {
        Group {
    switch state {
    case .error(let error):
        Text(state.stateName)
            .task {
                alert = (true, error)
            }
    default :
        Text(state.stateName)
    }
        }.alert(isPresented: $alert.isPresented, error: alert.error) {
            Button("Ok") {
                alert = (false, nil)
            }
        }
        .task {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            state = .error(.invalidId)
        }
    }
    
    struct Model {
        
    }
    
    enum LocalError: LocalizedError {
        //Use for any built in error
        case error(Error)
        //Use for something custom
        case invalidId
        
        var errorDescription: String? {
            switch self {
            case .error(let error):
                return error.localizedDescription
            case .invalidId:
                return "\(self)"
            }
        }
        var recoverySuggestion: String? {
            switch self {
            case .error(let error):
                let nsError = error as NSError
                return nsError.localizedRecoverySuggestion
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FooView()
}
```

This provides an independent `alert` variable so the presentation of the `.alert` does not conflict with the `View` behind it or make any unsafe assumptions.

Comment: very interesting, lemme try it

Answer (score 0):

##### Method 1 - Without helpers variavles

You can bind it directly to the `error` state like:

```
.alert("oops there was an error", isPresented: .constant(state == .error)) { Button("idle") { state = .idle } }
```

<sub>⚠️ note that the default `OK` button will not change the state in this method</sub>

---

##### Method 2 - With a `Binding<Bool>` variable in between

Another way is that you can wire-up the state to the binding:

```
var body: some View {
    let shouldShowError = Binding<Bool> {
        state == .error
    } set: { _ in
        guard state == .error else { return }
        state = .idle
    }

    Button(state.stateName) { state = .error }
        .alert("oops there was an error", isPresented: shouldShowError)
    { }
}
```

Note that there is no need to manually tell the view what to do like what we do in the `UIKit`, but you must declare what the state would be in every situation.

For this case, it is obvious that you need to see the alert on the `error` state, but it's not clear the other way. So you should filter it down to just 2 states (a `bool`) anyway.

Comment: So you are effectively creating a new binding on each redraw of the view. That is: not using a binding at all, but crating a workaround to pass a compilation. This is not a viable solution.

Comment: Many say this is different from UIKit, but when things get complicated, having many nillable variables mutually exclusinve (a variable for an error, a variable for the result, one for the filter, etc) get very messy very quickly. Add states for the animations this becomes unmaneageable. Enums with associated types are a very clean solution to all of these problems, and compile time safe. Thanks for the suggestion tho, i may come up with a property wrapper maybe using this approach, if it works i will accept

Comment: I have also added another method which is more straight forward to your needs. And may also satisfy @timbretimbre points

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use a computed binding like :

```
// show alert on error
    .alert("alert", isPresented: Binding<Bool>(get: {state == .error},
                                               set: {_ in})) {
            Button("idle", action: {state = .idle})
            Button("loading", action: {state = .loading})
            ...
        }
```